# Неопределенный аргумент в функции

Tags: c#

Предположим есть простая аргументная функция вида

```
public static void Toggle(Panel p) {
    p.Visible = !p.Visible;
}
```

Возможно ли задать неопределенный аргумент без типа, чтобы она применяла действие к любому заданному элементу, будь то панель, таблица или лейбл?

Comment: `public static void Toggle(Control p) { ...`

Comment: Спасибо! Добавь в виде ответа, а не комментария, подтвержу ответ зеленой галочкой =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перечисленные типы имеют общего предка - `Control`, в `System.Web.UI`, `System.Windows.Forms` или `System.Windows.Controls`:

```
public static void Toggle(Control p) { 
    p.Visible = !p.Visible;
}
```